# Using Tilt.js in Vue 3

Tags: html, css, vuejs3

I am building an application using Vue3 + Typescript and have found about the tilt.js.
I read about multiple ways of including it in the project, but none of the ways i tried seemed to work when adding `data-tilt` to HTML elements

**1. index.html references**

I began by using cdn to reference tilt.js in my index.html file like this:

```
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vanilla-tilt/1.7.2/vanilla-tilt.min.js" integrity="sha512-K9tDZvc8nQXR1DMuT97sct9f40dilGp97vx7EXjswJA+/mKqJZ8vcZLifZDP+9t08osMLuiIjd4jZ0SM011Q+w==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
```

**2. Downloading the file itself**

After the cdn method did not work out, i tried downloading the file [here](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/micku7zu/vanilla-tilt.js/master/dist/vanilla-tilt.min.js) and adding it to my src folder, then referencing it using

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/src/vanilla-tilt.min.js"></script>
```

**3. Install using npm**

I finally tried installing tilt.js using npm like this:

```
npm install vanilla-tilt
```

... and importing it to the .vue file of my desire as follows

```
import VanillaTilt from 'vanilla-tilt';
```

I guess there must be some step missing to all the solutions i tried, but i can not find anything online about it.
So how do i include vanilla-tilt in my Vue3 Project?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use the `data-tilt` attribute, it does work with the CDN link. See the following snippet.

```css
.box {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background: rebeccapurple;
}
```

```html
<div class="box" data-tilt></div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vanilla-tilt/1.7.2/vanilla-tilt.min.js" integrity="sha512-K9tDZvc8nQXR1DMuT97sct9f40dilGp97vx7EXjswJA+/mKqJZ8vcZLifZDP+9t08osMLuiIjd4jZ0SM011Q+w==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
```

When importing into Vue, you would not want to go with the `data-tilt` approach. There is a library called [vanilla-tilt-vue](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vanilla-tilt-vue) (which I haven't tried). If that's not your cup of tea, check out how the author made their component:

```
<template>
    <div :class="parallax ? 'preserve':''" id="tiltMe" ref="tiltRef">
        <slot></slot>
    </div>
</template>
<script>
import VanillaTilt from 'vanilla-tilt';
export default {
    name: 'Tilt',
    data: function(){
        return {
        }
    },
    mounted(){
        VanillaTilt.init(this.$refs.tiltRef,this.options)
    },
    props: {
        options: Object,
        parallax: Boolean
    }
}
</script>

<style>
.preserve{
    transform-style: preserve-3d;
}
</style>
```

The basic idea is that you build a `ref` to your HTML element and pass that into `VanillaTilt.init`.

Answer (score 2):

I tried using `vanilla-tilt-vue` and it wasn't working well plus it was messing up my html elements and so I switched to `vanilla-tilt` and it worked for me.

Setting up `vanilla-tilt` in **Vue 3** can be done the following way:

1. Install Vanilla tilt

   `npm i vanilla-tilt`
2. Copy this snippet and modify it accordingly

```
<script scope>
import VanillaTilt from 'vanilla-tilt'
import { onMounted, ref } from 'vue'

const element = ref(null)

onMounted(() => {
  VanillaTilt.init(element.value, { max: 20, speed:400 })
})
</script>

<template>
   <div class="cardBox" ref="element"></div>
</template>

<style scoped>
.cardBox {
   width: 200px;
   height: 100px;
   background: blue;
   border-radius: 5px;
}
</style>
```

Calling the vanilla tilt in the mounted and then passing the ref into the init.